# Comparison in low floating-point numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a method that performs roulette wheel selection.

```
action_to_execute=self.weighted_choice_sub(phermone_list)
def weighted_choice_sub(self,weights):
        '''performs weighted selection or roulette wheel selection on a list
        and returns the index selected from the list'''
        rnd = random.random() * sum(weights)
        for i, w in enumerate(weights):
            rnd -= w
            if rnd < 0:
                return i
```

At time it returns nothing, as in instead of index it returns `None`. This means that condition `rnd < 0` was never `True`.

```
(Pdb) phermone_list
[5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 1.5e-323, 5e-3 1.5e-323, 2.5e-323, 5e-324]
(Pdb) action_to_execute
(Pdb) type(action_to_execute)
<type 'NoneType'>
```

I can't understand what is happening, and how to fix it. I think it relates to the extremely low values in the list passed.

Update(debugging run):

```
(Pdb) phermone_list
[5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324, 5e-324]
def weighted_choice_sub(self,weights):
        '''performs weighted selection or roulette wheel selection on a list
        and returns the index selected from the list'''
        rnd = random.random() * sum(weights)
        print "____"
        for i, w in enumerate(weights):
            print (i,w)
            rnd -= w
            print rnd
            if rnd < 0:
                return i
(0, 5e-324)
3.95252516673e-323
(1, 5e-324)
3.45845952089e-323
(2, 5e-324)
2.96439387505e-323
(3, 5e-324)
2.47032822921e-323
(4, 5e-324)
1.97626258336e-323
(5, 5e-324)
1.48219693752e-323
(6, 5e-324)
9.88131291682e-324
(7, 5e-324)
4.94065645841e-324
(8, 5e-324)
0.0
```

Comment: have you tried adding print statements to your function to check the values of the variables at particular points?

Comment: I consistently get `5` every time, although I did have to add a missing comma to your `phermone_list` after the `5e-3`.

Comment: I also get 5, for what its worth.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Check the edit now please.

Comment: do you always get `None` or only sometimes? I ran a loop with edited `phermone_list ` value to do run the function `100000` times and `5645` of them returned None.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I get it sometimes.

Comment: If you want precise math, you can use `decimal` in python.  e.g., `decimals = map(decimal.Decimal, phermone_list)`.  It *will* make things slower!

Comment: FYI, just ran with `Decimal` for up to 1,000,000 iterations with no `None`

Comment: @rrauenza what does `Decimal` do?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html